# JMX mbean memory retentions and garbage collection

Tags: java, scala, garbage-collection, jmx, mbeans

I'm researching implementing JMX monitoring and I wanted to know how the JMX MBean server manages memory and when it releases its registered mbeans.

I've created a trivial example and am playing around with it and noticed that the objects weren't released and I was able to message them through JConsole long after the garbage collector should have kicked in. This leads me to believe that there is a huge potential for memory leaks in production and there could be unwieldily memory growth. For instance here I created 100 beans and messaged them through JConsole:

```
trait OrderTrackerMBean {
  def getOrderId : Int
  def setOrderId(orderId:Int)
}

class OrderTracker extends OrderTrackerMBean {
  var orderId = 0
  override def getOrderId: Int = orderId
  override def setOrderId(_orderId: Int)= {
    println(s"setting order id ${_orderId}")
    orderId = _orderId
  }

}

object TestJMX extends App {
  val s: MBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer
  0 to 100 map {
    x =>
      val objectName: ObjectName = new ObjectName(s"a.b.c.$x:type=basic,name=game")
      val orderTrackerBean = new OrderTracker
      s.registerMBean(orderTrackerBean ,objectName)
  }
  while(true) {}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are creating 100 Mbean objects and it will be live during the lifecycle of the JVM. It will still be referenced and hence this will not be collected during garbage collection.